# openvpn client configuration

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to my vpn server. I installed openvpn client on windows 10, copied ca.crt, client.crt and client.key from server and edited config file and here's what I'm getting in logs file

```
Options error: --cert fails with 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\‪client01.crt': No such file or directory
Options error: --key fails with 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\‪client01.key': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

Of course, the files are present in config directory.

Config file: http://pastebin.com/raw/zy1tXFnN

Comment: Has this been fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I found [this script](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) on github which generates you client config. After I copied generated cfg and run openvpn I was able to connect my vpn.

Comment: But that means that you no longer need help, right?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late for this answer and OP did not accept any answer yet. So here is my recent experience.

The easiest way I found to fix this problem is that copy your certificate or key files to the location mention under settings. Following is the way

1. Right click on the OpenVPN GUI in the taskbar
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Advanced, there you will already find location of configuration
   files. Just copy your client certificate or keys or any config files you need to that location.

You can also change the configuration location mentioned under settings. But in that case don't forget to copy your `ovpn` file to the updated location.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just checking that you're using the .ovpn config file for Windows?

I would try and remove the full file path, if your config file is in the same location as the crt files etc..., which I would think they are, just try using: `ca <name of ca file>.crt`

Alternatively, try placing the files in a folder and changing the file path in your config file to: `<folder name>\\<name of ca file>.crt`

Obviously, you need to move the other files into the same folder and modify their locations in the config file to the above format.

HTH

Comment: Yes, I'm using .ovpn config file placed in config folder for sure. Also I tried to change location of crt and key files, but it didn't worked. I even tried to paste them directly on C drive, but still the same errors. The strange thing is that, openvpn can find ca.crt file, but can't find client.crt and client.key even if there are placed in the same location.

Comment: That's odd.  Looking at the config file you have put up on your link above seems fine.  If you run the OpenVPN GUI and right click the icon in the system tray - then select "Edit Config", does that bring up the config file that you are editing? - I'm wondering whether it's looking for a completely different config file for some reason :/

Comment: I'm sure that config that I'm editing is file which pop out from "Edit Config", cause I wrote comment in file and it appear in ovpn file in config dir and also in file which pop out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry It might be very late, But I was also the facing same issue.

I found a workaround, as config file has  tag. I have created same tags for **cert** and **key** like below and added **client.crt** and **client.Key** content directly in config file.

```
- Added tags in config file <cert>copy client.crt text here</cert>
- Added tags in config file <key>copy client.key text here</key>
```

Import file in OpenVPN